# Android: How to retrieve FIT files via Bluetooth Garmin Watch

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, watch, garmin

I have a Garmin watch (Forerunner 25) which I use to connect with Garmin connect (Android app). For many reasons I would like to build my own custom app to track training. But I have **not** been able to do the following:

> 1. Connect android app with a bluetooth (Garmin) Watch for file transfer.
> 2. Retrieve a .fit file from the Watch via Bluetooth.

How would I be able to do this?
I have tried to connect the watch via a [BluetoothSocket](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket) but have had no luck to connect it.

```java
  UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
  mSocket = mDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
  mSocket.connect();
  //Never reaches this part, the connection is unsuccessful
  mOutputStream = mSocket.getOutputStream();
  mInputStream = mSocket.getInputStream();
```

Not sure If any of this is correct but this is what I started with.

```
//Note: The device is not null before I try to connect. 
// I can retrieve the name, the address ...
D/BluetoothUtils: isSocketAllowedBySecurityPolicy start : device null
W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
```

I know the .fit file is a bytefile so if anyone know how to convert it to a .csv file with all the information as: time, speed, length, elevation...

I have found the [Fitparser](https://github.com/dtcooper/python-fitparse) for python but not anything for Android.

- Is there any library for this?
- Or how could I parse a .fit (bytefile) to .csv on my own?